# A function trigger another function

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have a front element like this :

```
<nui-checkbox *ngFor="let optionManual of searchManuals | async" size="small" shape="round" fill="outline"
      (nuiChange)="selectManualOption(optionManual.manualId, $event.detail.checked)"
      [checked]="search.manualId.indexOf(optionManual.manualId) > -1">
      <span slot="end" class="button-inner"><span class="product-code">{{ optionManual.productCode }}</span><span
          class="volume" *ngIf="optionManual.pmVolumeText"> {{ optionManual.pmVolumeText }}</span>
        <nui-pill> {{ optionManual.language }}</nui-pill>
      </span>
   <div class="button-effect"></div>
</nui-checkbox>
```

I have to add a new feature and this feature have to filter the array `this.search.manualId`.

But when I call my function to filter it, it's trigger the change of some checkboxes on the component `nui-checkbox`, because, I guess, the `indexOf` in the `checked` property is changing.

Any idea to solve this issue ?

EDIT :
To clarify the point, I have 5 items in my base array :
`this.search.manualId = [Banana, Apple, Strawberry, Peach, Melons]`.

I create a new array by filter it :
`this.filterArray = [Banana, Apple, Strawberry, Melons]`.

My function, call by a new checkbox component, just do this :
`this.search.manualId = this.filterArray`.

But this call trigger the function `selectManualOption` in the `nuiChange` of checkbox component include at the top of this post and my array don't have anymore this 2 items : Peach (it's normal) and the last one Melons (it's an error).

EDIT2 :
`this.search.manualId` is an array of string but it's a part of an object. It's created in the constructor.

The total abject is define like this in the constructor of the page :

```
this.search = {
        id: -1,
        query: '',
        manualId: [],
        options: []
      };
```

then the manaulId array is create form a promise like this :

```
this.searchManuals.then(manuals => {
      this.search.manualId  = manuals.map(manual => manual.manualId);
      this.procedureManuals = manuals
        .filter(manual => PROCEDURE_MANUALS.includes(manual.productCode))
        .map(manual => manual.manualId);
    });
```

You can see also the filtered array : `this.procedureManuals`.

Then when I call the function to filter my array, I do that :

```
onSearchProcedureChecked(isChecked: boolean): void {
    if (isChecked) {
      this.search.manualId = this.procedureManuals;
    } else {
      this.search.manualId = this.allManuals;
    }
  }
```

Comment: how and when do you filter the `search.manualId` ?

Comment: I use a new checkbox. In fact, when you arrive on the page all checkbox are checked but not the new one. And when I check my new checkbox, it's call my function to filter the array.

Comment: You're checking all values matching search.manualId. So if you filter search.manualId, less checkboxes will be checked. I don't understand what different behavior do you wish ?

Comment: In fact, I have 5 checkbox in my test, normally with the filter, only the fourth checkbox is unchecked but indeed the fourth and the fiveth checkboxes is unchecked. An I see in my console, that the function `selectManualOption` is trigger but my new function don't call it.

Comment: the fourth and the fifth checkboxes sorry ;)

Comment: what is "your new function" ?

Comment: I have put some details in the post. No matter the name of the function I guess ? Or you want all the code ?

Comment: Thanks for details. Can you show the exact code which filters the array ? Is search.manualId an array of string, or an array of objects ?

Comment: In fact, I understand the issue but I don't know how to fix it : modify the `search.manualId` array, create a event just like check/uncheck a checkbox so it's trigger the nuiChange function...

Comment: I guess "optionManual" should have an attribute "isChecked", which you manually set. The issue is that you use a pipe async, you may use a subscribe instead, so you can store it, and use it...

Comment: No optionManual is an object from searchManuals : 
`*ngFor="let optionManual of searchManuals`
The issue is that I update the array `search.manualId` so it's triger a change on the checkbox so it's trigger the function on the `NuiChange`

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that I update the array `search.manualId` so it's triger a change on the checkbox so it's trigger the function on the `NuiChange`.
So I restart from the beginning and have now 2 arrays : one for the checkbox (I have call it `selectedManuals` and another one for the search : `search.manualId`.

And it's work fine :)

Anyway thanks for your help @Random